# how can I list-initialize my own class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want my own class can be list-initialized like vector:

```
myClass a = {1, 2, 3};
```

How can I do that using C++11 capabilities?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++11 has a notion of initializer lists. To use it, add a constructor which accepts a single argument of type `std::initializer_list<T>`. Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
struct S
{
  std::vector<int> v_;
  S(std::initializer_list<int> l)
    : v_(l)
  {
    std::cout << "constructed with initializer list of length " << l.size();
  }
};

int main()
{
    S s = { 1, 2, 3 };
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An `initializer_list` can be (like other STL containers) iterated and the `size` can be queried. This allows you to do as pointed in the other answer by yuyoyuppe to immediately feed it to a `vector`. But you may have other intents for your initialization and do something like execute an operation directly on the items of the list without copying.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct S
{
  int thesum;
  int items;
  S(std::initializer_list<int> l) :
    thesum(std::accumulate(l.begin(), l.end(), 0)),
    items(l.size())
  {}
};

int main()
{
    S s = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << s.items << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.thesum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
3
6
```

See:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/?kw=initializer_list
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list
  -